# limit on programmatically creating background process on windows

Tags: c#, windows

I have a parent application which creates a large number of the instance(200) of a child exe programmatically using

> process.start("app")

when I double-click on the parent exe the child exe's are created but if I try to execute parent exe on a remote machine using PowerShell or configure it to run on the web server when a request comes in it seems to be limited to 100 instances(background process). not sure if there is any limitations

Comment: Starting 200 instances of something seems a little... well.. XY'ish. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: because i want  each instance to do some batch processing

Comment: I recommend that you batch your "batch processing" processes themselves into a single batch _process_

Comment: @MickyD that would not fit my requirement

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/

Comment: You could use tasks to create workers within the same process. Unless you have a 200 core machine, you cannot expect 200x performance anyway. And if your tasks often wait for data (async)... there is not much of a difference either. So the only reason I see you would want that would be some obscure security requirements.